# Which Is A Better Way Of Writing Content Population?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Let's say I have 10 divs with unique IDs. When I click on an element within each I wish to show an overlay div and populate content within it based in the ID of the original div.

Is it better to do:

```
$('#inventory > div').find('i.icon-plus').on('click', function(){
    $('#add-item').slideDown(100);
    if ( $(this).parent('div').attr('id') == '#id1' ) {
        // load unique template
        // or
        // create form content here
    }
    else if ( $(this).parent('div').attr('id') == '#id2' ) {
        // load other unique template
        // or
        // create other form content here
    }

    ...

    else if ( $(this).parent('div').attr('id') == '#id10' ) {
        // load other unique template
        // or
        // create other form content here
    }
});
```

Or:

```
$('#inventory > div#id1').find('i.icon-plus').on('click', function(){
    $('#add-item').slideDown(100);
    // load unique template
    // or
    // create form content here
});
$('#inventory > div#id2').find('i.icon-plus').on('click', function(){
    $('#add-item').slideDown(100);
    // load unique template
    // or
    // create form content here
});

...

$('#inventory > div#id10').find('i.icon-plus').on('click', function(){
    $('#add-item').slideDown(100);
    // load other unique template
    // or
    // create other form content here
});
```

?

Basically what I'm asking is: is it better to have only one event handler with a ton of if/else statements or a ton of event handlers with no if/else statements, or does it not even matter?

Comment: I'd personally recommend using one event-handler, caching the `this.parentNode.id` and using a `switch` based on that `id`. However can you define 'better' in context? And, incidentally: [JS Perf](http://jsperf.com/).

Comment: Sounds like a good subject for a [JSPerf](http://jsperf.com/) test.

Comment: Thanks! Didn't know about that neat little tool.

Comment: Yeah definitely check out JSPerf but my opinion is you should use the latter. The first one you'll be going through many parentNodes just to check their id and then applying the template (this seems unnecessary especially if you know the id does exist). The latter is much cleaner and more understandable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you use [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to delegate your event handlers to the parent, thus avoiding jQuery having to attach handlers for each `i.icon-plus`.

Then use a map of handlers with ids as keys with functions that run their corresponding code. That way, you won't be appending a lot of if statements.

Each "case" may contain code that is repeating which, if we knew, could be further optimized. But since we don't know what each block of the mapped functions do, here's generic code which should serve the same purpose:

```
//add handles here, with id as the key and a 
//corresponding function that does what its supposed to do
var handles = {
  '#id1' : function(){/*do something*/},
  '#id2' : function(){/*do something*/},
  ...
}

//let's cache this one as well
var addItem = $('#add-item');

$('#inventory > div').on('click','i.icon-plus', function(e){

    //get the corresponding handler
    var handler = handles[$(this).parent('div').attr('id')];

    //return if the handler isn't defined for this id
    if(!handler) return;

    //otherwise, execute. the context and arguments are passed on
    addItem.slideDown(100);
    handler.apply(this,arguments);
});
```

This can be further optimized *if* the div referenced by `#inventory > div`, which is our [delegate target](http://api.jquery.com/event.delegateTarget/), is the same div as `$(this).parent('div')`. If so, it can be replaced to reduce function calls:

```
$(this).parent('div').attr('id')

//can be replaced by

$(e.delegateTarget).attr('id')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$("#inventory").children("div").on("click", "i.icon-plus", function (e) {
    console.log(e.delegateTarget.id);
    // Do your logic based on e.delegateTarget.id
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/7kyGP/

This binds one event to each of the "parent" (target) `<div>` elements. You use `.parent()` in your code, but you use `.find()` to get the `<i>`. That's kind of contradicting because `.find()` gets descendants...therefore `.parent()` won't necessarily be what you think it is if the `<i>` is nested. With this code, the `<i>` elements don't have to be immediate children - they can be descendants.

Inside the handler, `this` refers to the specific `<i>` element clicked, while `e.delegateTarget` refers to the element that the event is actually bound to - the children `<div>`s of `#inventory`. Of course, you can use jQuery to manipulate the target with `$(e.delegateTarget)`.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect there's a more generic approach here - if you can add the data you need as attributes to allow you to load the unique template or create form content then no need for lots of if statements or multiple event handlers.

**HTML**

```
<div id="inventory">
    <div id="id1" data-template-url="subform1.htm">
        ... some content
        <i class="icon-plus"></i>
    <div>
    <div id="id2" data-template-url="subform2.htm">
        ... some content
        <i class="icon-plus"></i>
    <div>
    <div id="id3" data-panel-id="panel3">
        ... some content
        <i class="icon-plus"></i>
    <div>
</div>

<div id="panel3" class="hide-until-required">
... panel content
</div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$('#inventory > div').find('i.icon-plus').on('click', function() {
    $('#add-item').slideDown(100);

    var templateUrl = $(this).parent('div').attr('data-panel-id');
    // or 
    var panelId = $(this).parent('div').attr('data-template-url');

    // do something with template or panel data
});
```